# How to add a subroute in controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, .net-6.0

I've created a controller class:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class CourseController : ControllerBase
```

I've got methods for the route declared in the attribute above but I also want to handle a subroute, eg. `"api/[controller]/{id}/course_subjects"`. I've tried adding the Route attribute to the method but after running the application I see a Swagger error and no response from that route when I type it in the browser.

The method:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<IEnumerable<SubjectDto>> GetCourseSubjectsList(string courseId)
{
    return await _courseProcessor.GetSubjectsForCourseAsync(courseId);
}
```

This is how I add the `Route`

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
[Route("api/[controller]/{id}/course_subjects/")]
public async Task<IEnumerable<SubjectDto>> GetCourseSubjectsList(string courseId)
{
    return await _courseProcessor.GetSubjectsForCourseAsync(courseId);
}
```

If I add the route directly in the HttpGet attribute, I get an error about the parameter being missing.

```
[HttpGet("{id}/course_subjects")]
public async Task<IEnumerable<SubjectDto>> GetCourseSubjectsList(string courseId)
{
    return await _courseProcessor.GetSubjectsForCourseAsync(courseId);
}
```

The error in the browser:

```
type    "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1"
title   "One or more validation errors occurred."
status  400
traceId "00-9c0f1c8198ed9573148cd3628c358ee3-87d7adc13bc3db77-00"
errors  
courseId    
0   "The courseId field is required."
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

you do not need `Route` attribute at all. You can specify the route in the `HttpGet`

`[HttpGet("{id}/course_subjects")]`

Comment: I was about to say this same thing exactly.

Comment: I tried that but got an error about the method parameter being missing `"The courseId field is required."`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. When I used the subroute in the HttpGet attribute, I didn't use a matching parameter name for the attribute and the method argument. In the attribute I used `id` and in the method argument I used `courseId`.

So the code should be:

```
[HttpGet("{id}/course_subjects")]
public async Task<IEnumerable<SubjectDto>> GetCourseSubjectsList(string id)
{
    return await _courseProcessor.GetSubjectsForCourseAsync(id);
}
```